# Universal "call" function

Tags: c++, c++11, template, reference

I need a function `call(f, args...)` which calls the "function" `f` with the arguments `args...`. It should be compatible with the following "functions":

1. Normal function pointers functors, lambdas, ... (= "callables"), call syntax: `f(args...)`
2. Member function pointers, call syntax: `(object.*f)(args...)` and `(ptr->*f)(args...)`
3. Member data pointers, call syntax: `(object.*f)` and `(ptr->*f)`

In the latter two cases, the `object` is the first of the arguments given to `call` and the `args...` the remaining arguments given to `call`. Also, they should work with objects, pointers and smart pointers (for which I assume the smart pointer class implements `operator*` returning a `T&`, so I don't use the syntax `ptr->*f` but rather `(*ptr).*f`).

As I thought there is no such thing in the standard library (but I remember they have something similar, e.g. they have `mem_fun` as a wrapper which could be useful here), I wrote it by myself.

Currently, the member versions (2. + 3.) are only needed for `const` objects/pointers and `const` member function/data pointers.

```
// 1.
// Normal function call (also supports functors / lambdas)
template <class Fn, class ...Args>
auto call(Fn &&f, Args && ...args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


// 2.
// Member function call on instance
template <class T, class Ret, class ...Args, class ...ProvidedArgs>
Ret call(Ret (T::*memFn)(Args...)const, const T &x, ProvidedArgs && ...args) {
    return (x.*memFn)(std::forward<ProvidedArgs>(args)...);
}
// Member function call on dereferenced raw pointer
template <class T, class Ret, class ...Args, class ...ProvidedArgs>
Ret call(Ret (T::*memFn)(Args...)const, const T *x, ProvidedArgs && ...args) {
    return ((*x).*memFn)(std::forward<ProvidedArgs>(args)...); // or ->*
}
// Member function call on dereferenced smart pointer
template <class T, class Ret, class SmartPtr, class ...Args, class ...ProvidedArgs>
Ret call(Ret (T::*memFn)(Args...)const, const SmartPtr &x, ProvidedArgs && ...args) {
    return ((*x).*memFn)(std::forward<ProvidedArgs>(args)...);
}


// 3.
// Member variable on instance
template <class T, class Ret>
Ret call(Ret (T::*memVar), const T &x) {
    return (x.*memVar);
}
// Member variable on dereferenced raw pointer
template <class T, class Ret>
Ret call(Ret (T::*memVar), const T *x) {
    return ((*x).*memVar); // or ->*
}
// Member variable on dereferenced smart pointer
template <class T, class Ret, class SmartPtr>
Ret call(Ret (T::*memVar), const SmartPtr &x) {
    return ((*x).*memVar);
}
```

Is there something to be improved (performance-wise, usability-wise, ...)? Can you think of a different case of "functions" which can be useful to be supported by my `call` function?

My open questions about the current implementation are:

- Is my use of universal references and `std::forward` correct to achieve "perfect forwarding" to the target function? In case 2., I'm not sure if I should put `Args` or `ProvidedArgs` in the template parameter of `std::forward`. I need two packs to be deduced separately for the function type and the parameters for the case they don't match (but can be converted).
- Should the smart pointer parameter in cases 2. + 3. be a universal reference `&&` or `const&`? Currently I use `const&`.
- Should the function parameter in case 1. be a universal reference `&&` or `const&`? Currently I use `&&`.

Comment: A different class of functions that would be good to support are objects with overloaded operator () such as lambdas and std::function.

Comment: @nwp Thanks, but that's already handled with case 1 (edited to clarify).

Comment: I think [this](http://ideone.com/tgPQyu) should compile but doesn't. The perfect forwarding works fine. `&&` or `const &` makes no difference here because all you do with the pointer is calling it, so having a temporary or not does not matter.

Comment: @nwp: It can. If you pass an object and hold a const reference to it you can not call a non const function on that object.

Comment: @LokiAstari Overloads 2 and 3 only get called for member function pointers. It does not matter if the member function pointer is `const` or not. For overload 1 with objects you are right, it would not always work with `const &`.

Comment: @nwp I intentionally only support `const` functions; your example uses a mutable function. Modifying your example compiles. Of course I could add overloads for mutable functions (which are then called on mutable objects/pointers), but the code base in which I use `call` doesn't need it currently.

Comment: I'm confused on two points: what does the client code look like such that `call` is advantageous over the direct `(obj.*meth)(args...)` etc., and why do the member variable accessors in case 3 not actually call anything, yet share the function name `call`?

Comment: @MichaelUrman It's advantageous by being consistent with the normal function call: both can then be called with the exact same syntax `call(f,args...)`. That's useful for some functions in my library, which should accept any kind of functions (could be function member pointers) as parameters, and calls them with objects of any kind (could be pointers). Think of a `map` function (like in Haskell) which you give a sequence of any type (could hold pointers) and a map function, could be a member function pointer: `map(vectorOfStrings, &string::size)` is very readable code without *any* boilerplate

Comment: I just noticed that the overloads with `T*` can be simply removed, since `SmartPtr` can be deduced to `T*`. I of course gave `SmartPtr` a different name since it doesn't have to be a smart pointer anymore: `PtrT`

Comment: @MichaelUrman Ah and about the member data pointers (case 3): That's to also support them with the same syntax; maybe the name "call" is a bit off here, but I couldn't find a better name. Elaborating on my other example with `map`, consider a POD type `class Point { int x,y; };` which you want to have the top-most, i.e. with maximum `y`, from a sequence of points: `max(points, &Point::y)` is what my client code will end up being, very readable in my opinion. And if the designer of `Point` switches to getters/setters this client code doesn't even need to be adapted (if the getter is called `y`)

Comment: Now we have `std::invoke`.